# Creating a derived document in MS Word

Tags: ms-word

Is it possible to create a dynamic document derived from a second document? For example a student document that contains problems, and then a teacher's version which has the exact same contents as the student one, but has additional paragraphs with discussion points and solutions.
The dynamic part is important so that if changes are made to a problem in one document the other gets updated.
Perhaps using hidden text and only copying the non-hidden parts to the second document?

Comment: Look into the review features of MS Docs, keeping it in the same document will be easier. Why wouldn't you allow the student to see the notes and teaching points as well? in this scenario if there is many students and one teacher, then it probably makes more sense to keep the teacher document separate and the teacher can open the docs side-by-side. I would write an application interface around facilitation of the process, rather than trying to force this type of interface into MS Docs themselves... That said you could use content controls and addins... It can be done, but should you do it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Chris Schaller. I was more concerned about the solutions being kept separate but always in-synch with the problems. I didn't want them to have access to the solutions until they had been discussed. In the "old days" one could just print out the document with hidden text suppressed, but distributing digitally means that the data can be looked up. I will look into the application interface.